# How to play a wolf head ninja optimally

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature

From [Pathfinder SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/alternate-classes/ninja/archetypes/rogue-genius-games-ninja-archetypes/wolf-head)

> **Primal Cunning (Ex**) While a wolf head lacks the focus and training to
> access a ki pool, he does have an honed sense of primal, animalistic
> cunning that allows him to draw on reserves of puissance and tenacity
> that border on the supernatural. This acts as a ki pool (and qualifies
> as a ki pool for prerequisites), but it contains only a single ki
> point. However, even if the wolf head expends this ki point, he is
> able to use tricks that require him to have at least one ki point.
> Along with ruffian, this ability replaces the ki pool ability.

My interpretation of this ability is that a wolf head ninja does not use ki at all for his ninja tricks, but there's also the capstone for ninja and various other abilities that require ki

From [Pathfinder SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/alternate-classes/ninja/#Hidden_Master_Su)

> **Hidden Master (Su)** At 20th level, a ninja becomes a true master of her
> art. She can, as a standard action, cast greater invisibility on
> herself. While invisible in this way, she cannot be detected by any
> means, and not even invisibility purge, see invisibility, and true
> seeing can reveal her. She uses her ninja level as her caster level
> for this ability. Using this ability consumes 3 ki points from her ki
> pool. In addition, whenever the ninja deals sneak attack damage, she
> can sacrifice additional damage dice to apply a penalty to one ability
> score of the target equal to the number of dice sacrificed for 1
> minute. This penalty does not stack with itself and cannot reduce an
> ability score below 1.

From [pathfinder SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/alternate-classes/ninja/#Ki_Pool_Su)

> By spending 1 point from her ki pool, a ninja can make one additional
> attack at her highest attack bonus, but she can do so only when making
> a full attack. In addition, she can spend 1 point to increase her
> speed by 20 feet for 1 round. Finally, a ninja can spend 1 point from
> her ki pool to give herself a +4 insight bonus on Stealth checks for 1
> round. Each of these powers is activated as a swift action. A ninja
> can gain additional powers that consume points from her ki pool by
> selecting certain ninja tricks

what I got from all this is that the ki system is pretty much useless to a wolf head ninja because most of the ninja features either require you to have at least 1 point left or use 1 point for activation. Furthermore the ninja class seems heavily focused around ki usage even outside of tricks. So that begs the question how do you play a wolf's head ninja given the regular ninja guidelines won't apply.

Comment: @Ifusaso I rolled back your addition of the tag as we don't make tags for 3rd party publishers as per [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8714/48759).

Comment: @linksassin: To clarify, we don't have a generic tag for third-party content in general (any longer, at least). As doppelgreener's answer mentions, "Some notable publishers (like [dreamscarred-press]) might have dedicated tags about their material, but this is rare." And KRyan's comment notes: "But the tag mostly makes sense for questions that are like “what is my best option for doing this thing, in a game that allows this DSP content?” which is a thing we’ve seen from time to time. [...] Individual elements from DSP content might get tagged that way, but it’s probably not entirely right."

Comment: @V2Blast Understood. I did this because I was checking the newly created tags for ones without tag wikis. I noticed two 3pp tags that had been created by adding them to questions. I checked meta for our policy and that meta seemed to indicate we didn't need them. So I removed them. If this is incorrect I'm happy to be overruled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. Take the Extra Ki feat.

If you don't like having only one Ki, you can get 2 more at the cost of a [feat](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/extra-ki/) as many times as you like.

### 2. Buy/have crafted for you a Ki Mat.

The [Ki Mat](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ki-mat/) wondrous item allows you to recover your spent Ki with an hour of rest and a DC 10 Wisdom check. It's costly (in low level money and time) but can be the difference between enjoying your character or not.

### 3. Request a friendly Cleric take the Ki Channel feat.

[Ki Channel](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/ki-channel/) would allow you to recover your 1 Ki instead of health each time your Cleric channels energy to heal. This is mostly beneficial if you also invest in Extra Ki and/or your party has another (vanilla) ninja or monk.

### 4. Have a planned use-situation for your Ki Point(s).

Decide on something your character cares about (getting an extra attack against leader type characters, on a Flat-Footed target, etc.) and only use your Ki in that situation. It will (hopefully) feel more thematic than gimpy.

### 5. Always remember the large bonuses you gained for your lower pool.

Wolf Head provides a +16 Fort bonus by level 20 and 20 extra HP on your d8 HD. The closest approximation to this benefit is 3 feats (Toughness, Great Fortitude and Improved Great Fortitude; even this doesn't compare fully) and access to 3 unique Ninja Tricks aimed toward successful Intimidation.

Answer (score 2):

**You can play the wolf head with tricks requiring one ki point left**

> However, even if the wolf head expends this ki point, **he is able to
>   use tricks that require him to have at least one ki point**. Along with
>   ruffian, this ability replaces the ki pool ability.

(Emphasis mine)

> What I got from all this is that the ki system is pretty much useless
>   to a wolf head ninja because most of the ninja features either require
>   you to have at least 1 point left...

Your assumption here seems to be wrong - and it would be the main draw of the wolf head: continuous access to trick requiring one ki point, even when you don't have any left.

So you can capitalize on that by picking mainly tricks that are continuous bonus as long as you have one ki point. The wolf-head archetype basically transforms them into flat-continuous bonus.